# Telerik Wpf RadControls Multiline TextBox

Tags: .net, wpf, telerik

I am developing a Wpf application using Telerik RadControls. Do you know any of their controls that is like a multiline TextBox?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valentin, Telerik WPF controls didn't offer any TextBox/Multiline editor controls until they released the new Q1 2011 version.

This version includes a new [RadRichTextBox](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/richtextbox.aspx) control.  If you have an active licence with Telerik i would suggest downloading the update from March 16, 2011.  Otherwise they did support theming of the windows control TextBox but didn't provide an alternative.